# Regarding closing a new open workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro which allows users to put the path in a `Textbox` & open the file.

However, once the file is opened and data is copied I want the macro to close the newly opened workbook. Since the file opened could always be changed what code do I need to close it?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Cmd_1_Click()
    Dim Wbk As ThisWorkbook
    Dim Wbk1 As Workbooks
    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application

    Set xlapp = New Excel.Application
    Set Wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set Wbk1 = Workbooks

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If Txt_1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Path Entered, please enter path to proceed", vbRetryCancel, "Path Missing"
    Else
        Wbk1.Open(Txt_1.Value).Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Copy

        Wbk.Activate
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

        MsgBox "Done"

        Set xlapp = Nothing
        Set Wbk = Nothing
        Set Wbk1 = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `.Close`? But I think I just don't understand the question. Can you be a bit more clear and provide example code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a workbook the `Open()` function has a return value: the workbook object you just opened. Save it in a variable and use the `Close()` method on it to specifically close that workbook afterwards:

```
If Txt_1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Path Entered, please enter path to proceed", vbRetryCancel, "Path Missing"
Else
    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(Txt_1.Value)
    Wbk.Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Wbk.Close False

    MsgBox "Done"
End If
```

Make sure `Wbk` is declared as `Workbook` (that is an object type) and not as `ThisWorkbook` (which is an object rather than a type).

There is a lot of unnecessary variables and code in your module. You should probably remove everything that isn't needed. And please study this code in detail to understand *why* it is working. It seems to me you are still not grasping the concepts of how objects are used in VBA.

Comment: This would add a workbook & then close it, however i want to close the workbook that user has opened by inputting the path

Comment: Actually what my Macro does is it opens the file from the path given by user, it then copies the data from the new workbook & paste the data in the EUC File. I however want to close the file opened by the user after the data is copied however since the EUC file becomes the active workbook I cannot close the file opened by the user since the path may always Vary.

Comment: What is StrFileName here.?

Comment: The file name is not known here so i cannot give the file name if u want me to gibe the file name for strfilename

Comment: Of course it is known, you said so yourself: "*[...] Macro which allows users to put the path in Textbox & open the file.*" -- that's `strFilename`.

Comment: Unable to send the pic of my coding. Can i have your email address so that i can send the image

Comment: Please do not make a screenshot of your code. Just edit your original question and copy & paste the code there. Make sure you format it as code. There are buttons above the text field that make it real simple to format your question.

Comment: It says i need to have minimum of 10 reputation credits to post image.

Comment: As I said: do NOT make a screenshot of your code! Paste the code as text and then format it afterwards as code.

Comment: I added the Code... Can you help?

Comment: Although my previous answer was perfectly fine and worked well, I updated it so it now incorporates parts of your code.